# Alternative for System.out.print in Android

Tags: android

Could someone tell me what is the alternative for `System.out.print` in Android?

Comment: @?????? hello curd  its not answer

Comment: It's pretty much not a serious question also

Answer (score 11):

```
Log.d("SOMETHING", "Content");
```

The `d` above is for debug messages, but you can also use with `i` for information messages and `e` for error messages (and `v` for verbose). Now you may think... how do I see that output? well, you use the `logcat` which is a tool inside the SDK. If you use eclipse and the ADT plugins, you can see the `logcat` output from there.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `System.out.println()`. You will see the output in the Logcat.

Comment: right, i think it is in green text color then. note that you can't say if it is an error, warning or a info message by color because it is all green. that is not with the Log.X("Y","Z"); command, it is simply better for debugging purpose.

Comment: Yes thats true. But the to answer the question I thought this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use logcat window in eclipse
Window menu -> Show View -> Other -> find LogCat
And see all output
Either you write system.out.println() or Log.i()...

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String TAG = YourActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Prints a string followed by a newline
System.out.println(TAG + " " + VARIABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print
System.output.print
System.out.echo
```

Comment: how to print the value of string

Answer (score 0):

@polopok
Hm... Not that correct I think.

Check the code guidelines : http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#logging

Log.d(), Log.i(), Log.w(), etc should be the way to go.